# Laravel variable increments value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm having a weird issue, I have two foreach loops inside blade. when I use the id value of the model received from the first foreach loop and use it inside the second foreach loop the value increments suddenly.

Livewire component:

```
class HomePage extends Component
{
    public $subjectComments = [];
    public function loadSubjectComments($type, $id)
        {
            $article = Article::findOrfail($id);
            $this->subjectComments[$article->id] = $article->comments;
        }
}
```

in the blade:

```
    @foreach($activities as $activity)
        <a wire:click="loadSubjectComments('{{$activity->subject_type}}', {{ $activity->subject->id }})" @click="showCommentTextBox{{ $activity->subject->id }} = ! showCommentTextBox{{ $activity->subject->id }}" class="cursor-pointer">
            <div class="flex flex-row pr-2 justify-center text-center items-center">
                <div>{{$activity->subject->comments->count()}}</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        {{$activity->subject->id}} //at this level the value is correct
        @if($subjectComments)
            @foreach($subjectComments[$activity->subject->id] as $index => $comment) //here the value of $activity->subject->id increments by 1
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

it gives this error "Undefined array key 6" where the id actually is 5 when reading from {{$activity->subject->id}}

Comment: I wondered how your code works without exception error with this typo }

Comment: Because this condition `@if($subjectComments)` is not true for all the ID's

Comment: I didn't copy paste it, I wrote it in StackOverflow, thank you

Comment: @user2682025 Copy/pasting is the preferred way though, there might be typos in your original code that don't get transferred when typing. Just fyi ;)

Comment: @SahilGupta that's not the problem, the problem is in the second foreach loop

Comment: How did you check that `$activity->subject->id` increments in the second loop? So you `{{$activity->subject->id}}` again after the `@if`?

Comment: @brombeer because it gives this error "Undefined array key 6" where the id actually is 5 when reading from {{$activity->subject->id}}

Answer (score 0):

So a few things here,

1. It's not given that the `$subjectComments` variable holds any data for that activity, since the check for `@if($subjectComments)` only checks that there is at least one comment for *any* activity, not just the one you are iterating. You can fix this by using the null coalescing operator in your loop.
2. When using lops in Livewire with dynamic content, you should be using `wire:key` and only have one root element in your loop.

```html
@foreach($activities as $activity)
    <div wire:key="activity-{{ $activity->id }}">
        <a wire:click="loadSubjectComments('{{ $activity->subject_type }}', {{ $activity->subject->id }})" 
           @click="showCommentTextBox{{ $activity->subject->id }} = ! showCommentTextBox{{ $activity->subject->id }}" 
           class="cursor-pointer"
        >
            <div class="flex flex-row pr-2 justify-center text-center items-center">
                <div>{{ $activity->subject->comments->count() }}</div>
            </div>
        </a>
        {{ $activity->subject->id }}
        @if($subjectComments)   
            @foreach($subjectComments[$activity->subject->id] ?? [] as $index => $comment) 
                <div wire:key="comment-{{ $comment->id }}">
                </div> 
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```